# Multiple Controls on Infopath Form not working

Tags: 2010, infopath, forms-services

On my form after a section that was hidden is shown due to conditional formatting all option buttons and checkboxes on the form seem to lose the binding to their datatypes.

What happens is that any conditional formatting that is tied to them no longer occurs and whatever value they have when this happens it is locked in. Meaning if, after it seems to break, I change the value and proceed to hide or show a section the value of the option button changes back.

This only happens when the form is on the SharePoint server, previewing it in InfoPath does not show this problem.

Has anyone else come across this before? If so how do I fix it and what causes it? Is it possible that the style sheet or theme that the server uses could cause this?

edit: there is a workaround that I have used and that is changing the option buttons to a drop down box. This is not ideal as that would mean I'm not able to trust using option buttons again until I can find the cause of this problem, because the only reason I know this problem exists is because of selecting Cannot be blank in the properties of the option button.

Edit: I originally thought this was isolated to a single form but it now seems that is not the case. I also had thought it was caused by nested sections but this isn't true either. I have a form that has multiple hidden sections, none of them are nested inside one another and it was made a couple months after I had made the last one.

The versions of software I am currently using are InfoPath 2007(12.0.6529.5000) and SharePoint server 2010

Comment: Simply executed and awesome approach to share such a wonderful content, I swill start working on the same question.

Answer (score 1):

When you configure the options buttons in InfoPath, you have to go into each one of them and set the value of the option. Since the required fields does not seem to go away when using the browser, it sounds like this value is not set correctly. However, if the values are set the same, you might also see this problem, as both will be selected when one option button is selected.

I would start with making sure each option is configured with the appropriate data (boolean or text are the easiest). Also, if you are using conditional formatting via rules from these options, the value of the condition is case sensitive... Yes does not equal yes. So double check that as well.

Comment: I made sure that they both have different values and the required check is because I checked "Cannot be blank" in the properties. So this isnt what the problem is. 

I have other option buttons on the form that are showing the same problem when the drop down box is set to other. Didn't notice them before because they are the first thing on the form and therefore the first thing you fill out.